# Get button focus by hovering over the card - Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How can I get button focus when hovering over a card in Bootsrap in any place. Currently, the button focus requires hovering over the button. I would like to get the effect as in the photo two after hovering over any place in card.

[image]

Code:

```
  <style>
  .hovernow {
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }

  .hovernow:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    border:2px solid #3E7DC0;
  }
  </style>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xl-3">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="bg-body hovernow rounded-3 text-center p-2 position-relative" style="border:2px solid #6f42c1;">
        <!-- Image -->
        <img src="{% static 'assets/images/persons/5.png' %}" class="img-fluid mb-3" alt="">
        <button class="btn btn-primary-soft text-white w-100">Age: 18-24</button>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

U cant't use `button` in `a` tag.
No, it isn't valid HTML5 according to the [HTML5 Spec Document from W3C](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

try like this:

```
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xl-3">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="bg-body hovernow rounded-3 text-center p-2 position-relative" style="border:2px solid #6f42c1;">
        <!-- Image -->
        <img src="{% static 'assets/images/persons/5.png' %}" class="img-fluid mb-3" alt="">
        <span class="btn btn-primary-soft text-white w-100">Age: 18-24</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some JS here to set button focus on hover. Maybe something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div.hovernow').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).children().closest('button').focus();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, You can use `.stretched-link` bootstrap class for that. your code should be as below.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xl-3">
      <div class="bg-body hovernow rounded-3 text-center p-2 position-relative" style="border:2px solid #6f42c1;">
        <!-- Image -->
        <img src="{% static 'assets/images/persons/5.png' %}" class="img-fluid mb-3" alt="">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary-soft text-white w-100 stretched-link">Age: 18-24</a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Please read bootstrap docs for more information here: [Stretched link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/helpers/stretched-link/)